# Images in div align to left and div display in center with responsive view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to align image container in center and images should be in serially and aligned to left to it's parent div.

```css
.imgDiv{
text-align:center;
}
.imgDiv img{
text-align:left;
width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgDiv">
<img src="img1">
<img src="img2">
<img src="img3">
<img src="img4">
<img src="img5">
<img src="img6">
<img src="img7">
<img src="img8">
<img src="img9">
<img src="img10">

</div>
```

in my code images aligning in center to div, but images should be to the left of that div, div should be center in page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically question is wrong.

Because when you align div into center, div covers the screen as per itself width and left space aside and if images(multiple) align to left in this situation, defiantly it'll not cover whole div width and div have some space into right and it'll not look center.

And 2nd case if all images covers the whole parent div space, how you'll identify its aligning left until images will not fall into 2nd row and have some empty space in the end.

Comment: Right @himanshu. i understood that what you are saying. but can't wen align images in a center with responsiveness?

Comment: This codepen example will help you in that. https://codepen.io/greatzspido/pen/ZXRJZW.

Answer (score 0):

For div should be center give `max-width` as you want and `margin:0 auto;`.

```css
.imgDiv{
  margin:0 auto;
  max-width:95%;
}
.imgDiv img{
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgDiv">
<img src="img1">
<img src="img2">
<img src="img3">
<img src="img4">
<img src="img5">
<img src="img6">
<img src="img7">
<img src="img8">
<img src="img9">
<img src="img10">
</div>
```

Comment: div not aligned in center in your code, right side more space is occupying.

Comment: @ankita In responsive images not aligning in to center. div only aligning to the center.

Comment: @VijjuSena you are not mention that you want in responsive view.